# Passing information/variables from one webpage to another in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object, location, href

How can I pass on variables from one webpage to another? Till now, I know that I can pass the information in the link/location but don't know how to pass without the use of form. As in forms we use 'get' as method to pass the info but when we are using a link or without anything then how can I pass?
Also is there any other way to transfer information from one webpage to another (except the link way/location way)?
I use the following method to transfer info using the form get method, but don't know how I can I transfer without the form!

```
function getVar(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  var returning="Not given"
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");

    if (pair[0] == variable) {

      if (variable=="checkin" || variable=="checkout") {
            var properdate=pair[1].split("%2F");
           var finaldate=properdate[0]+ "/"+ properdate[1]+ "/"+ properdate[2];
        return finaldate;
      }

      return pair[1];
    }
  } 
  return returning; 
}
```

Comment: If you own both websites you can do it with session in either node or PHP, or whatever you are using for your back-end code.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at jQuery. With jQuery, you can get any variable from form or any thing else easily. And it also help you send data throw AJAX. Ex

```
$('form').serialize();
```

Will get all data from form as object
...
http://jquery.com/